# What permission required for user to customize tabs in lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, permissions, tab-settings

How can user customize tabs in lightning like moving around the tabs or removing the tabs instead of admin do those task for the users? in other worlds allow users ability to customize tabs by themself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Lightning

There is no specific permission required (aside from not being an API-only user), but there are specific conditions that must be met. First, the App being used must be a Lightning App. Second, the app must have the *Disable end user personalization of nav items in this app* checkbox **unchecked** (Setup > Apps > App Manager > Edit > App Options).

If both of these conditions are met, when the user switches to the App, they will have a ✏️ icon in the upper-right corner, indicating that the tabs can be customized. They can drag tabs around to reorder them, use the down-chevron on any tab to create a List View tab, or use the aforementioned pencil icon to add, remove, or rename items.

Users cannot remove items added by an administrator but may otherwise customize the display. If you don't see the icon for an app, either it is either disabled, a Classic app, or some other special apps that don't support customization; you can create a new App to give to your users instead.

Note also that there is a cap of 50 navigation items, so if you place 50 items into an App, no more items can be added by users. Try to keep your app as focused as possible if you want to give users a lot of space to create their own layout.

[image: Nav menu with pencil icon]

[image: Editing nav menu items]

Also see [this video](https://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/JgMPthKFTK68JeZpjx8MXH) for more functionality.

## Classic

All users can freely customize their tab layouts without restriction (aside from not being able to remove or move Home). They simply click on the ➕ icon, then click on Customize My Tabs (also available under Personal Setup).

---

[image: Classic Tab Customization]

---

[image: My Settings]

[image: Customize My Tabs in My Settings]

---

Either way, you end up here:

[image: Customize My Tabs screen]

Here, you can choose an app to customize, and add/remove tabs. The only requirement you need to access this screen is to not be an API-only restricted user.